# Promise.all() fail when additional mongoose model.save() is added in

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mocha.js

I am getting Mocha error in my Promise.all when running 4 mongoose model save, but it is fine when running only 3 mongoose model save. Here's the sample code under the describe () => {}.

```
// Blog and Tag are mongoose models.
beforeEach((done) => {
    myBlog = new Blog({ title: '1st Post' });
    myBlog2 = new Blog({ title: '2nd Post' });
    tag1 = new Tag({ tag: 'Tag 1' });
    tag2 = new Tag({ tag: 'Tag 2' });

    myBlog.tag.push(tag1, tag2);        
    myBlog2.tag.push(tag1);
    tag1.blog.push(myBlog, myBlog2);
    tag2.blog.push(myBlog);

    Promise.all([myBlog.save(), tag1.save(), tag2.save()])
        .then(() => done());
});

it('find myBlog', (done) => {       
    Blog.findOne({ title: '1st Post'})
        .then((blog) => {
            assert(blog.title === '1st Post');
            done();
        });
});
```

Above code runs well, however when I replace the initial Promise.all code to the include myBlog2.save(), I got an error.

```
Promise.all([myBlog.save(), myBlog2.save(), tag1.save(), tag2.save()])
        .then(() => done());

"before each" hook for "find myBlog":
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Why is it that adding an additional model.save() into Promise.all() causes an error?

I checked mongodb and the collections did save successfully. However, I don't believe the it('find myBlog') code ran at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the DB is far away from you , or it's on a very slow machine,

you may really exceed the 2 seconds timeout .

you can control it via .timeout(ms) like this:

`it('mytest', done => {}).timeout(5000)`
or `beforeEach().timeout()`

will make the timeout to 5 seconds .

Read more about it [here](https://mochajs.org/#test-level)

Hope it helps,
Good luck !

Comment: the db is local in my pc. I also found out it works outside mocha framework.

Comment: Please share with me ? What did you do differently ?